# Passing a custom variable from a PayPal button after a user subscribes

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on a subscription service for a test website of mine. I have the infrastructure in place so that when a user registers, they need to subscribe before going to their profile. How can I tell if a user has finished subscribing? I have a flag in my database that will turn to true after they subscribe, but I can't seem to figure out that last handshake.

I tried to set it up when making the button to go to "http://www.example.com/profile.php?completed=true" so that I can simply look for that completed variable, but paypal seems to ignore that. Any thoughts on how to do that?

Upon looking at a similar post on here, I could redirect to a success.php, where it can update the database flag. This is a work around, but is this the only solution? Or is there one similar to what I originally wanted to do? Thanks for your input everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

`Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, like automatically fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status.`